# Getting file names from String array

Tags: java, android, arrays, file

I am not sure if I asked the question 100% right but here it goes:
I got this code:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File saveFolder= new File(Root, "Save");

        String[] files=saveFolder.list(
           new FilenameFilter() {
               public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
               //define here you filter condition for every single file
                   return name.startsWith("1_");

               }
           });

        if(files.length>0) {
            System.out.println("FOUND!");
            System.out.println("Files length = "+files.length);
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND!");
        }
```

I got 2 files that start with `"1_"`, the `println` also shows I got 2 files.
But how can I print or see, the file names, of those 2 files, after the boolean?

So something like (between the other `System.out.println`):

`System.out.println("File names = "+files.names);`

Comment: can you please stop starting your variables names with capital letters?

Comment: I did it for you - next time: **never ever** use variable names that start with a capital letter in code you post at SO. (.. if you want that people look at you code ;) )

Comment: Ok, I will pay more attention next time.
Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the array:

```
String[] files=SaveFolder.list(...);
for (String name : files) {
    System.out.println("File name: " + name);
}
```

Note that the naming convention of variables is to start them with lower case.

Comment: Thanks, never knew you could do a for loop like that? That's java only I assume (never saw/used it in C++)

Comment: This is the for-each loop: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html You can do it with a regular loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
file.getName(); // for the name of the file
file.getAbsolutePath(); for the full path of the file
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 public boolean accept(File dir, String Name) {
           //define here you filter condition for every single file
               return Name.startsWith("1_");

           }
```

with this:

```
 public boolean accept(File dir, String Name) {
           //define here you filter condition for every single file
               boolean b = Name.startsWith("1_");
               if (b)
                     System.out.println(Name);
               return b;

           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Arrays.asList() if you want to quickly print out a primitive array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(files));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some code to the if block:

```
if(files.length>0) {
   System.out.println("FOUND!");
   System.out.println("Files length = "+files.length);
   // next lines print the filenames
   for (String fileName:files)
        System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use personally if I need filenames to load in a load function.

```
public void getFiles(String path){
        //Store the filesnames to ArryList<String>
        File dir = new File(path);
            ArrayList<String> savefiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
            savefiles.add(file.getName());
        }
        //Check if the filenames or so to say read them
        for (int i = 0; i < savefiles.size(); i++){
            String s = savefiles.get(i);
            System.out.println("File "+i+" : "+s);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

I hope this helps C: